# Porting WSAStringToAddress into WinRT

Tags: c#, c++, .net, network-programming, windows-runtime

So, I'm porting some code to WinRT, and for reasons too masochistic to explain here, I'm trying to port some code that relies very, very heavily on WinSock and IPAddress, so I'm writing my own implementation of IPAddress, and I'm stuck on WSAStringToAddress, or, more broadly, implementing IPAddress InternalParse (takes string, spits out IPAddress).

It seems that everyone uses library functions, (for good reason), which don't appear to exist reasonably in WinRT. (And Googling it as an 'interview question' doesn't seem to get any results)

Does anyone have a decent way of going string -> IPAddress for both v6 and v4?

Edit:

Would this work, reasonably?

```
    private static unsafe IPAddress InternalParse(string ipString, bool tryParse)
    {
        HostName hn = new HostName(ipString);
        IPAddress ipAddr = new IPAddress(GetBytes(hn.ToString()));
        return ipAddr;
    {

    private static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: Please put more thought and less rant into your questions. Especially the title, which is of no real use in its current form.

Comment: Tweaked to address that. Thanks!